# Increasing length of an arrow in 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Initially, I have:

```
a = Plot3D[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 5}}];
Show[a, Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 4}}]]]
```

To increase the length of the arrow, I change the commands into

```
a = Plot3D[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 5}}];
Show[a, Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 10}}]]]
```

but the arrowhead disappear. How to make the arrowhead visible **without changing the range** of the plot?

Comment: Using `PlotRange -> All` in show. See the linked answer for why this is necessary.

Comment: Can we do it without changing the `PlotRange` @Szabolcs?

Comment: No, because if the PlotRange is smaller than the arrow, then not all of the arrow will show.